# What is wrong with the below statement(C#3.0 / Lambda)

Tags: c#-3.0

what is wrong in the below

```
Enumerable.Range(0, objEntityCode.Count - 1).Select(i => 
{ 
options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey 
{ 
EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes 
, OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE }; 
})
.ToArray();
```

Throwing error The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

But this works

```
Enumerable.Range(0, objEntityCode.Count - 1).ToList().ForEach(i =>  
                { 
                    options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey 
                    { 
                         EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes 
                         , OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE   
                    };  

                } 
             );
```

Using C#3.0.

Purpose: I am learning LINQ / LAMBDA and trying to do the same program in different way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in a comment - your lambda expression doesn't return anything. Therefore it can't be used in a projection. `Select` is meant to transform a sequence of items of one type into a sequence of items of another type. You're not doing any transforming in your lambda expression - you've just got an assignment.

Now you *could* do this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, objEntityCode.Count - 1).Select(i => 
{ 
    return options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey 
    { 
        EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes,
        OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE
    }; 
})
.ToArray();
```

I wouldn't recommend it though. I appreciate you're currently learning about LINQ and lambda expressions, but it's worth learning when *not* to use them too - and this looks like a situation where you really, really shouldn't use them.

Comment: As a purely intellectual exercise, it actually *would* return something if the semicolon were omitted from within the statement (since it would then be a single-line lambda, which doesn't require the `return` statement).

Comment: @Adam. You would also need to remove the braces around the lambda as a statement in braces with no semicolon will not compile.

Comment: As in `i=>{i+5}` won't compile, but `i=>i+5` will.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you have inside the `Select` and `ForEach` method calls:

```
options.Attributes[i] = new EntityCodeKey 
    { 
        EntityCode = objEntityCode[i].EntityCodes 
        , OrganizationCode = Constants.ORGANIZATION_CODE   
    };
```

This is essentially an `Action<int>` -- that is, code that *does* something but doesn't *return* something. This is why it makes sense within `ForEach` but not `Select` -- `Select` expects (in this case) a `Func<int, T>` -- code that *returns* something (of some type `T`). Since you are simply assigning `Attributes[i]` to a new `EntityCodeKey`, this code does not fall under the umbrella of what you would normally find within a `Select` call.

Note that *technically*, the above code actually *would* return something -- namely, the value stored in `options.Attributes[i]` -- if you removed the semicolon from the end. Why? Two reasons:

1. A single-line lambda expression (not terminating in a semi-colon) returns whatever it evaluates to. This is why something like `person => person.Name` can actually be interpreted as a `Func<Person, string>`.
2. An assignment operation evaluates to the assigned value. This is why you can write `x = y = z` -- because `y = z` actually evalutes to the newly assigned value of `y`.

So it's true: your code, sans semi-colon, would actually evaluate to `options.Attributes[i]`. But writing the code in this way would be, in my opinion anyway, pretty confusing.